# Moment display seconds as 'm:ss'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I am trying to use moment to display `2` seconds like this `0:02`.

I expected the following code to work but unfortunately it just displays as`0:00`. This is based on [this](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) section of the docs.

```
moment(2).format('m:ss');
```

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong? I have read through the docs and tried numerous approaches with no luck.

Comment: Since it accepts milliseconds you would have to provide `moment(2000).format('m:ss')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it as

```
moment().minutes(0).second(2).format('m:ss')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4eqL594p/

But this also sets minutes as 0.

EDIT: As another answerer had pointed out, you could also do

```
moment({seconds: 2}).format('m:ss')
```

Comment: that's ok man! works as i want! ill give you the green tick asap!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Unix](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) method, it accept an integer value representing the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC)

Example:

```
moment.unix(2).format('m:ss');
```

Demo:

```js
console.log(moment.unix(2).format('m:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```